# Angular Materials mat-list options (Is it possible to positioned check-boxes left?)

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

The `mat-list` control is featured here: 
https://material.angular.io/components/list/overview

Is it possible to start the list items with the checkbox in front of them ( rather than postfixing them at the end due to defaults )?

I tried this but no luck!

```
/* mat-list: atempt to move the checkboxes to the far left */
.mat-pseudo-checkbox {
  left: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: `<mat-list-option checkboxPosition="before"></mat-list-option>`

Comment: maybe read the API doc before creating a question?

Comment: dude, I read it but I just missed it. material docs is not their best.

Comment: This is a perfectly valid question. Stackoverflow encourages all questions - even where the answer is 'readily available'. And it's much easier to search for the problem than try to guess what they've called it. The examples are sorely lacking in many of the material docs - and why checkboxPosition has a default of 'after' I have no idea.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Each component has an API section that gives you additional features:

https://material.angular.io/components/list/api#MatListOption

```
<mat-list-option togglePosition="before"></mat-list-option>
```

You can set the `togglePosition` to either `before` or `after`.
https://material.angular.io/components/list/api#type_aliases

Comment: cgatian, this does answer the question. but I was expecting a CSS based solution. Now I'm able to position the checkboxes on the left, but positioning them slightly higher is not possiblle. Do you know how to tackle the positioning from a CSS point of view?

Comment: Could you make a stackblitz with and a picture of what you want?

Comment: labelPosition : before or after Indicates whether label should appear before or after the checkbox

Comment: 'checkboxPosition' has been deprecated. use 'togglePosition' instead